# Horizontal Popover Items

Tags: ios, popover

Below is a function I have in my project, that calls a popover menu with the buttons Delete and Lock once the user long presses. The buttons are currently listed vertically and show at the bottom of my selected element.

How would I go about getting the buttons to show horizontally and for the popover to show at the top of my selected element and centered?

```
- (void)showMenu:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSArray *menuItems =
    @[

      [KxMenuItem menuItem:@"Delete"
                     image:nil
                    target:self
                    action:@selector(deleteTouchUpInside:)],

      [KxMenuItem menuItem:@"Lock"
                     image:nil
                    target:self
                    action:@selector(lockButton:)],

      ];

    [KxMenu showMenuInView:self.view
                  fromRect:recognizer.view.frame
                 menuItems:menuItems];

}
```

Comment: What kind of object is KxMenu?

Comment: @rdelmar, probably one of these: https://github.com/kolyvan/kxmenu

Comment: If you need to use the KxMenu, then you'll need to write that logic in yourself to re-arrange the stack of buttons horizontally rather than vertically. It looks like the menu tries to place itself in whichever space is available, defaulting to below, first.

Comment: I think it is a UIMenuItem, but from the source of code I got it from, which you just referenced in the link, I don't know know exactly where to change it and make the items show horizontally.